# How to debug scheme if statment

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I find myself often wanting to examine statements and print what's going on there. For example, using this basic example:

```
(define (example-debug lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (example-debug (cdr lst))))

(example-debug '(1 2 3))
```

How could I put displays in both parts of the `if` statement? Using python as an example, I might have something like this:

```
def example_debug(lst):
    if not lst:
        print ("End of list reached")
    else:
        print ("Element is: %s" % lst[0])
        example_debug(lst[1:])
```

Is there a clean-ish or similar way to do that on the above in scheme? How are non-trivial programs usually 'debugged'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` will be cumbersome to debug with print statements, because you can't write more than one expression for the consequent or the alternative, forcing you to use `begin` if you want to do more than one thing (I'm using `printf` which is specific to Racket, adjust to your interpreter):

```
(define (example-debug lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      (begin
        (printf "End of list reached~n")
        '()) ; this proc always returns '(), not very useful!
      (begin
        (printf "Element is: ~a~n" (first lst))
        (example-debug (cdr lst)))))
```

It'll be slightly more readable with a `cond`, which has implicit `begin`s:

```
(define (example-debug lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (printf "End of list reached~n")
         '())
        (else
         (printf "Element is: ~a~n" (first lst))
         (example-debug (cdr lst)))))
```

But to really answer your question: don't use prints to debug :). A good IDE (say, Racket) has a built-in debugger.

Comment: thanks for all this. What is `printf` (I assume like C)? I don't get that as a built-in when using `#lang sicp`. Also, I'm using racket. Any good tutorials or an example of how to use the debugger to see the values?

Comment: `printf` is kinda like a simplified version of C's, it's available in `#lang racket`. For `#lang sicp` you can use `display`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/debugger.html) regarding the debugger.